# .NET MVC3 Stongly Typed Form Helper not passing the data to the action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Model Wrapper class that wrap another model:

```
public class LogicPage {
    public MyPage Pg { get; set; }
}

public class MyPage {
     public string name { get; set; }
}
```

In my create form view I use strongly typed form helper:

```
@model MyAppCore.Components.LogicPage
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","PageAdmin",FormMethod.Post)) {
     <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pg.name)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pg.name)
 </div>
 ...
}
```

In my controller, I define the action as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(LogicPage logicpg)
{
   return View("View",logicpg.Pg);
}
```

However, when the MyPage Pg is displayed in the "View" which list details of the model (MyPage), no user inputted data are shown, the details of the page shown are all MyPage default values (initialized with default no parameter constructor of LogicPage).  Looks like data in the form are not passing to the model in the action.  Can someone please help me why the data is not passing?

To clarify more, I have two views "Create" form view of model LogicPage and the "View" detail view for model MyPage

Create.cshtml

```
@model MyAppCore.Components.LogicPage
```

View.cshtml

```
@model MyAppCore.Components.MyPage
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the difference between LogicPage and LogicCmsPage significant, or just a typo in the question?

Comment: Sorry, Just typo... it should be LogicPage

Comment: Why are you passing an instance of MyPage (logicpg.Pg in your code) to the view as the model when the model expects an instance of LogicPage. MyPage doesn't appear to inherit from LogicPage, so this shouldn't even work.

Comment: the View "View.cshtml"  is created by me for debugging, it is expecting MyPage class.  It is the Form "Form.cshtml" expects the LogicPage Class.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're doing

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(LogicPage logicpg)
{
   return View("View",logicpg.Pg);
}
```

But given that MyPage doesn't inherit from LogicPage, and your view expects an instance of LogicPage, I think  you should be doing:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(LogicPage logicpg)
{
   return View("View",logicpg);
}
```

Comment: The View.cshtml actually is taking MyPage as a model
   @model MyAppCore.Models.MyPage

Comment: The CreateForm.cshtml takes LogicPage as model, while the View.cshtml takes MyPage as model

Comment: @user1416492 - but you're passing a LogicPage to View as well, because form's model is LogicPage.